# Marker not place on correct position after zoom in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

After zoom in google map,marker is not place on correct postion in google map
-Marker takes wrong place but coordinates are right so what's problem in my code i don't know.
Anybody can help??
Here is code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=uk&language=en&sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         var lat = 39.399872,
             lng = -8.224454,
             latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
             image = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png';

         var mapOptions = {
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
             zoom: 8,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
             zoomControl: true,
             zoomControlOptions: {
                 style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
             }
         },
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions),
             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: latlng,
                 map: map,
                 icon: image
             });

         var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
         var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
             types: ["geocode"]
         });

         autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

         google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function (event) {
             infowindow.close();
             var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
             if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                 map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
             } else {
                 map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                 map.setZoom(17);
             }

             moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
             $('.MapLat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
             $('.MapLon').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
         });
         google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
             $('.MapLat').val(event.latLng.lat());
             $('.MapLon').val(event.latLng.lng());
             infowindow.close();
                     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                     geocoder.geocode({
                         "latLng":event.latLng
                     }, function (results, status) {
                         console.log(results, status);
                         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                             console.log(results);
                             var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                                 lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                                 placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                                 latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                             moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
                             $("#searchTextField").val(results[0].formatted_address);
                         }
                     });
         });

         function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
             marker.setIcon(image);
             marker.setPosition(latlng);
             infowindow.setContent(placeName);
         }
     });
</script>
</head>

<body>

Address:
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" style="text-align: left;width:357px;direction: ltr;">
<br>
latitude:<input name="latitude" class="MapLat" value="" type="text" placeholder="Latitude" style="width: 161px;" disabled>
longitude:<input name="longitude" class="MapLon" value="" type="text" placeholder="Longitude" style="width: 161px;" disabled>

<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 275px;width: 800px;margin: 0.6em;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tested your code and it works well. Please, explain your problem in more detail

Comment: ya..it works well..zoom in map to 15-17 and then click on any place marker is not move on that place it place on other place..

Comment: There is only a single marker(what do you mean by "any") and nothing happens when I click on this marker, because there is no click-listener for the marker(the marker also doesn't move when I click on it). Nothing in your code seems to be related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on accuracy of maps. I mean, you can set marker only on defined places, which depends on accuracy of maps. But coordinates always change. So I think code works well and here is no errors or bugs.